# Android layout shift to right side of screen in micromax device

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a form in my app, it view render correctly and center  in some of my phone but in micromax phone it shifted to right side of screen.
Below is screen shot - [image]

and below is my xml code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen20"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_tv"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text14"
            android:textColor="#A9A9A9"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:text="@string/create_announcement_message"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type_tv"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title_tv"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text14"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:text="@string/select_message_type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/text_rb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/type_tv"
            android:text="Text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen10"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/image_rb"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text_rb"
            android:layout_below="@+id/type_tv"
            android:text="Image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen10"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/title_et"
            android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text_rb"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text14"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#A9A9A9"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/enter_title_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/message_et"
            android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title_et"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text14"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#A9A9A9"
            android:minLines="5"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="@string/enter_message_hint"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_container_rl"
            android:layout_below="@+id/message_et"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:background="@drawable/input_bg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/choose_image_tv"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="Select image"
                android:textColor="#A9A9A9"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text16"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_iv"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text16"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen20"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:text="@string/submit"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bottom_round_bg"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

i tried alot but not found any solution to it.
Any help much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line..

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```